# android mobiles connectivity using TP-link wireless outdoor CPE

Tags: wireless-networking

I am Internet service provider and I would like to know if we can provide internet service to android mobiles using TP-link wireless outdoor CPE. If we can. How can we maitain track of individual user (IP-Mac), Maximum users allowed for 1 CPE and also want to know if it is valid as per trai rules or not.

Comment: Thank you for providing this information. Please let me know if these type of connections are valid as per trai rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can provide the service but you cant track using IP address as mobile phones will have not have static IP's it will be by default set to DHCP. You need to track using Mac addresses see this for more info

http://www.tp-link.in/article/?faqid=359